# What is the meaning “这是后话”?

Tags: meaning

Does it mean 'another story'?
This is the phrase that came to my mind first.
Is there any other corresponding English phrase?

Comment: jukuu： 此是后话 ＂we anticipate", 1.  If you had seen these clothes after-but, as the shilling shockers say, we anticipate.
 如果事后你见到了这些衣服—但是，用一句廉价惊险小说里的话说，此是后话，暂且按下来不表。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The counterpart of “这是后话” in English should be " That is a story for another time." meaning some future events are related to the story, but not the focus of the current story arc. The author may or may not revisit it in later part of the story.

Answer (score 1):

I think it means that this is some description which supplements after the event.

It is similar to 後記, but 後記 always contains lots of statement, whereas 后話 is always both shorter and spoken by someone instead of being written.